# How do I update an object in Firebase specific property?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

I am trying to update a User in Firebase using Angular 4 with AngularFire2. In the user object that tis saved to the firebase database, I want to insert another object into an array property. In my service I am trying to do this functionality (I already have everything in keys etc also)

```
generateUserCharacterList(){
  this.genCharList = new CharacterList(x, y, z)
  this.UserListOfCharacters.push(this.genCharList)
  //Other code...
}
```

This does not work though

Comment: Can you add more information?

Answer (score 0):

The [Update specific fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) documentation indicated usage of the `.update` method.

> ```
> function writeNewPost(uid, username, picture, title, body) {
>   // A post entry.
>   var postData = {
>     author: username,
>     uid: uid,
>     body: body,
>     title: title,
>     starCount: 0,
>     authorPic: picture
>   };
>
>   // Get a key for a new Post.
>   var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('posts').push().key;
>
>   // Write the new post's data simultaneously in the posts list and the user's post list.
>   var updates = {};
>   updates['/posts/' + newPostKey] = postData;
>   updates['/user-posts/' + uid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;
>
>   return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I am considering that you are using the firebase realtime database as compared to the firestore.

You should take the value of the array in a variable, change the value, and then call the update method on the object ref with that new value. Here is the code sample for the explanation:

```
let userRef = db.object('users/aad1asd123-123asd');
let user = userRef.valueChanges();
let listOfChars = user.listOfChars;

listOfChars.push('a');
listOfChars.push('b');
listOfChars.push('c');
listOfChars.push('d');

userRef.update({listOfChars: listOfChars});
```